# How does length contraction apply while distances increase in the Lorentz transformation?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I am having trouble settling the difference between the math in the length contraction equation and the Lorentz transformation. Say there is a piece of wood traveling near the speed of light and you swing two axes to chop it simultaneously. If the proper length of the piece of wood is longer than the distance between the axes, the length of the wood would contract with respect to the rest frame where the axes are being swung and it would then not be cut. From the point of view of the wood, the distance between the two axes would contract and thus it would be cut. I understand that the events would not actually happen in this order from the point of view of the wood and perhaps the right axe would actually land first and then the left one would follow. What I don't understand is in this scenario the length between the two axes should still be contracted but in the lorentz z' transformation it results in a greater distance. The equation would be z'=γz with γ being positive resulting in the right axe being further from the left axe at origin 0 than it was in the rest frame. This would result in a greater distance between the two axes according to the piece of wood rather than a contracted length. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried reading the many people talking about the barn-and-pole paradox?

Comment: Simultaneity is frame-dependent. Which frame do the two axes chop simultaneously?

Comment: Look up space time diagrams for graphical representations. Think it comes down to events not really being simultaneous

Answer (score 0):

$(x_1-x_2)^2-(t_1-t_2)^2$ is invariant.
That means that whenever a length measurement is made at equal times in one Lorentz system, the length will be shorter than when it is measured at different times for each end in any other Lorentz system.
For the system where the log is moving, you have each axe moving at the same time. This means that in the rest system of the log, the log will be longer, but so will the distance between the two axes, which still miss the log.

Answer (score 0):

In the rest frame of the axes, the axes appear to fall simultaneously but the wood is untouched because it contracted and fits between the axes. In the rest frame of the wood the front axe falls just before the wood arrives, but due to the relativity of simultaneity, there is a delay before the rear axe falls, giving time for the wood to pass between th e closer together axes, before the rear axe falls.

This is basically a version of the Train Tunnel Paradox ([Video here](https://than%20the%20proper%20distance%20between%20the%20axes.)) or the Barn and Pole paradox ([Video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVhI45_WzJ4)) or the  [Ladder Paradox (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_paradox).

They are all explained by [The Relativity of Simultaneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity).

Answer (score 0):

The situation is similar to a pair of ships with a distance of $3.9$ ly flying to Alpha Centauri, passing by the earth in its path. The distance of the star from the Earth is $4$ly in our frame. But with a big enough relative speed, it can be the case that, from the frame of the ships, this distance is contracted to 3.8ly.

As the ships are in the same frame, its clocks can be synchronized. So, they can arrange to register its position relating to the celestial bodies each day. There will be some days when one of them is already ahead of Alpha Centauri, while the other is still behind the Earth.

The 'wood' is the distance between Earth and Alpha Centauri in our frame. The 'axes' are the ships.

You may object that from our frame, it is the distance between the ships that are contracted. It is true, but the day when the ship close to us records its position is earlier (in our frame) than when the ship close to the star records its position. When the same day comes to it, (that is: when it is the same day in the ship's frame) it is already ahead of the star.